# How can I implement this navigation style used by the InList app?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiviewcontroller, custom-transition

I'm trying to recreate a navigation feature similar to the one used in the InList app. They have quite a nifty way of sliding from one screen to the other.
[image]

Basically, the main screen is a table view with different events for a given city. Tap the button in the top left “London” and the table view ​*zooms*​ out to show the table views for the other cities.

You can scroll right/left to select a different city.

Tap on and the screen ​*zooms*​ back in with the new table view.

My questions:

#### a) Does anybody know if this is a plugin? If so, can you please link it?

#### b) If it's not a plugin. Can you outline the basic steps you'd take to approach developing this solution for yourself?

Thanks

Comment: In your place I'd look at `UICollectionView`, `UICollectionViewLayout` where every cell in collection view has a `UITableView`. It may be tricky and not straightforward to get it working well, though.

Comment: @Losiowaty thanks for the heads-up!